# Are there any states in US that allow healthcare premiums to increase without limit?

Tags: united-states, healthcare, affordable-care-act

My understanding is that **most** states have an insurance commission that (among other things) is tasked with approving health insurance premiums in that state.

In answer to a previous question, the respondent said "Only in states where premiums can increase without limit. Some require regulatory approval of increases."

Comment: My guess would be that is the whole basis behind the phony "let companies sell across state lines..... to improve competition" argument.

Comment: for clarification: the previous related to insurer's reluctance to move into a market where the is no competition; to which the respondent suggested that insurers would only be interested in states where they could charge premiums without regulatory control.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: Yes. Some states do not limit health insurance premiums.

Long Answer:

The National Conference of State Legislatures [summarizes health insurance rate regulation on a state by state basis](http://www.ncsl.org/research/health/health-insurance-rate-approval-disapproval.aspx). The really short summary is found in this map:

[image]

But, the map really doesn't do the story justice. You need to, at least, review the extensive footnotes, and honestly, you need to dig even deeper than that to get a meaningful understanding of the process, because some superficially similar state insurance regulation programs are much more rigorous than others on an as applied basis.

Comment: Very useful link, it appears that 5 states do not have **Federally** approved rate review programs. Whether those five states have a premium review program (not federally approved) it looks like I may have get on the phone to find out.

Comment: @BobElston I agree that it takes more information to really get to the bottom of it, but this is one of the better starting points to that search of which I am aware.